# Process.Start Functionality

Tags: c#, c++, .net, winapi

Does the Process.Start method call the underlying Windows API function CreateProcess?

Looking at the Microsoft documentation it appears [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) can be used in either C++ or C# but [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) can only be used in C++.

I'm just trying to determine if one function utilizes the other and if that's the general case for API calls in C# vs C++.

Comment: `CreateProcess` can be used in C# via PInvoke, but there's no point in doing so as `Process.Start` does indeed do so internally.

Comment: It depends. It calls `CreateProcessWithLogonW` or `CreateProcess`. The functions that are invoked come from `Microsoft.Win32.NativeMethods`. At least, this is what I could see when using `Reflector`.

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,e9edeff01b1851af

Comment: All .net methods/classes can be called from C++/CLI, i think that is what the example in the MSDN is referring to. You can't call `Process.Start` from native code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 possible native functions it could call depending on the settings in the `StartInfo` you passed in.

- If `UseShellExecute = true` it will call [`ShellExecuteEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx).
- If `UseShellExecute = false` and you set a username then it will call [`CreateProcessWithLogonW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431(v=vs.85).aspx).
- If `UseShellExecute = false` and you did not set a username then it will call `CreateProcess`.

You can follow the code yourself via the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,e9edeff01b1851af).

If you wanted to call `CreateProcess` directly (or any native function) you would need to perform a "[Platform Invoke (P/Invoke)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx)". There are websites that help you figure out the P/Invoke signatures [for common functions](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/CreateProcess.html). This process is a lot more complex and involved and it is just simpler to just use `Process.Start`.